# Who wrote this incredible theme-song?

Tags: buck-bumble

If anyone here remembers a game for the Nintendo 64 by the name of "Buck Bumble" you **will** remember how awesome the theme song that played at the main menu was.  Can anybody tell me who wrote this song?  I would really like to know.

If you haven't heard the Buck Bumble Theme yet, you should.  [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0DDY299Ly4) is a link.

Comment: oh geez, this is going to be stuck in my head all day

Comment: damn here we go...

Comment: Why do i feel like i was just rick rolled?

Comment: @jblaske its like an audio version of tvtropes

Comment: Read the title, glanced at tags, song started playing. There goes my thoughts for the rest of the day

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Justin Scharvona](http://www.last.fm/music/Justin%20Scharvona).

Comment: How in Internet's name did you find this??

Comment: Shazam didn't find it